# mysql select month from timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, timestamp

I have a mysql query but it's not working properly yet. The idea is: I have a month calendar, so I select all items with the current month form my db.

I select TV show episodes, they air on a specific date but they are available the next day. I want to have the available dates in my cal. So a specific example: An episode aires 2013-03-31 and is available on 2013-04-01. This episode will not be selected from the db. I have tried something like this:

```
$this->db->where('MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_aired+86400))='.$month);
```

But it didn't work. Does anyone know a solution? This is my full code:

```
$this->db->select('*, episodes.overview as overview, episodes.id as ep_id, shows.id as id');
$this->db->from('episodes');
$this->db->join('shows', 'episodes.imdb_id = shows.imdb_id');

$this->db->where('CHAR_LENGTH(episodes.ep_title) > 1');

$this->db->where('MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_aired))='.$month);
$this->db->where('YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_aired))='.$year);
$this->db->order_by('episodes.first_aired', 'DESC');

$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you able to get the next date from previous date first of all..if you are able to get then use this date('m',$date);

Comment: Does the code without the `+86400` work? On a test database, using today's timestamp, a direct SQL query like so produces an expected result (aka, returns next month's items): `SELECT * FROM test WHERE MONTH(FROM_TIMESTAMP(first_aired + 2592000)) = 5`. So this type of query works. Have you looked at the generated SQL? Eg, `echo $this->db->last_query();`. As a side note, why are you using unix timestamps anyway? You should be storing these dates as `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQLs [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
select mydate, date_add(mydate, interval 1 day) from testdata;
```

So if you want to get the month of the next day, use `month(date_add(...))`

```
mysql> select mydate, date_add(mydate, interval 1 day) "next day", month(date_add(mydate, interval 1 day)) "month of next day" from testdata;
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| mydate     | next day   | month of next day |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 2013-01-31 | 2013-02-01 |                 2 |
| 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-02 |                 1 |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So for your query, use something like `$this->db->where('MONTH(DATE_ADD(first_aired, INTERVAL 1 DAY))='.$month);`. Oh, and you might have to add a `FROM_UNIXTIME` here and there.